# Can I use Blender to create 3D wall image viewer application under Linux?

Tags: python, user-interface, opengl, blender

Is that possible to use Blender to create Cooliris-like 3D wall image viewer application under Linux?

I don't see many people use Blender (BGE) to create desktop application, so I am wondering if this is possible. People normally use Blender for modeling/movie and game engine. 
I can not find a good way to create 3D application in Linux so far.

I was thinking about pyQT+opengl. But I feel that is hard to do. No robust and easy-to-use qt+opengl toolkit available from my research. I know a little bit of Blender, that's why I am asking if Blender is an alternative solution. (python is preferred)

The image viewer doesn't have to be windowed. It can be full screen, like a game?. I would like to add many cool effects into this application. Hopefully cooler than Cooliris which is written in flash.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [Clutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutter_%28toolkit%29).  Looks like it has Python bindings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I never knew Clutter. It looks GOOD.

Comment: Between, could you please list some well-known application which uses Clutter if possible? thanks.

Comment: I did some googling for Clutter. It is very good. but there is just one problem. It's written in C and all docs are written for C. I can not find many good tutorial/docs/examples for pyclutter...

Comment: @sgon00: There's an "examples" directory in the pyclutter source tarball (http://www.clutter-project.org/sources/pyclutter/1.0/).

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip. I tried some of the examples. looks very cool. Between, if you read this post, I am just wondering if anyone use blender to create desktop application instead of game? blender looks a real 3D engine to me than clutter. but clutter is cool and should be much easier for me to create desktop application. I think I will learn clutter for now and maybe look at blender in the future when I have time. thanks.